# Running test on Chrome Browser Testng

Tags: java, selenium

```
package org.testngsessions;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestRegist {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    }
}
```

This code can not open google chrome. What am I doing wrong? In eclipse I get Only local connections are allowed.

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:
```

Comment: There is no problem with your code. It runs perfectly fine on my system. Check if your chrome driver version is `2.40` and Chrome above version `66`.

Comment: Yes both are updated. is selenium site there s chrome driver for 32 bit only my windows is 64 bit. can this be the reason ?

Comment: Should not be the reason. I am running on same. Are you behind any kind of proxy?

Comment: No not at all. I suspect something about the ports though

Comment: switch this:     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

Comment: I found out that it doesnt start gecko mozilla driver too. It must be about environmental settings. what do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

Change your driver version to "chromedriver-2.35"

Comment: I am using windows 10  turkish version. I ve tried the same with a laptop with windows 10 english and it works.

Comment: Selenium methods are not compatible with non english operating systems. I changed my windows 10 O.S. to english and it works fine now. The solution is o.s language.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded latest 2.40 chrome driver and Your code worked for me.

So You probably have issue with driver or if using maven, try updating your client / server

//client //

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

//server//

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>  
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and check latest chrome driver here:
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Hope this helps,

Title says: `System.out.println(driver.getTitle());` "My Store" :)

Comment: Hi thanks. I m not using mvn. maybe reinstalling eclipse and all can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Use the chrome driver with "no-sandbox" option with above code.it will work. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks it says " Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure." again. It can not start up chrome or mozilla